# How to check JSON response in Spring MVC test

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-mvc-test

I have a servlet defined in web.xml, so I defined it inside a Controller for testing only for `MyResource`:

```
 @Controller 
 public class TestMyServlet {

     MyResource servlet;

     @Autowired
     AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFac;

     @PostConstruct
     void init() {
         servlet = new MyResource();
         beanFac.autowireBean(servlet);
     }

     @RequestMapping(value = "/servlet/api/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
     public MyResponse handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @RequestBody String json) {     
         return servlet.update(json);
     }
```

Then I test it using `MockHttpServletRequestBuilder`:

```
  MockHttpServletRequestBuilder mockHttpServletRequestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders
    .post("/servlet/api/update")
    .content("{\"id\":1,\"toggle\":true}]")
    .session(httpSession)
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    MvcResult mvcResult = this.mockMvc.perform(mockHttpServletRequestBuilder)
              .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
              .andReturn();
    ModelAndView modelAndView = mvcResult.getModelAndView().getModelMap();
    String response = mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString();
```

In servlet I don't use `ModelAndView`, just returning a POJO object (`MyResponse`) that is serialize to JSON response

I'm seeing `MyResponse` object as a second attribute in `ModelAndView`, but `response` is null

How can I check JSON string returned in this response?

Comment: Debug the code. See what's happening. Log the response or add logging and see where is it null

Comment: @SagarKharab in my code I'm only returning an object which is fine, the question is about how to test it using Spring `MvcResult`

Comment: maybe completely off topic, but is there a typo in  @RequestMapping(value = "/servletapi/update" ?

Comment: @Daniele only typo, my endpoint working and returning POJO successfully

Answer (score 2):

There is one way here, i hope i understood the question correct ,

```
MockMvcRequestBuilders
.post("/servlet/api/update")
.content("{\"id\":1,\"toggle\":true}]")
.session(httpSession)
.contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
.andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].key",is("value")));
```

**andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].key",is("value")))**

you can use this for each key and value.

**Or**

try this ,

```
 MockMvcRequestBuilders
.post("/servlet/api/update")
.content("{\"id\":1,\"toggle\":true}]")
.session(httpSession)
.contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
.andExpect(content().string(containsString("value")));
```

Comment: method `is(String) is undefined`, what is the static import?

Comment: import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;

Comment: we don't use `hamcrest` yet

Comment: Sorry but also `method containsString(String) is undefined`

Comment: i am so sorry i didn't realize its again from hamcrest, but would it not solve your problem if you use it?