# Spring MVC Test missing imports from MockMvc example

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-mvc-test

I'm trying to test using [Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867824/how-to-check-json-response-in-spring-mvc-test), but even when using example from [MockMvc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/MockMvc.html):

> ```
> .andExpect(status().isOk())
> .andExpect(content().mimeType("text/html"))
> ```

Using `MockHttpServletRequestBuilder`:

```
MockHttpServletRequestBuilder mockHttpServletRequestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders
        .post("/servlet/api/update")
```

I'm getting 2 exceptions:

> ```
> The method andExpect(ResultMatcher) is undefined for the type MockHttpServletRequestBuilder
>
> The method mimeType(String) is undefined for the type ContentResultMatchers
> ```

I'm using the import from example (below), but still seems that I'm missing other imports

> ```
>  import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.*;
>  import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;
>  import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders.*;
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the complete code is not posted it's difficult to guess what would be the mistake. I post working code here, that might help.

```
         mockMvc.perform(post(path)
                    .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .accept(APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .header(AUTHORIZATION, BEARER_AUTHORIZATION)
                    .content(mapper.writeValueAsString(webRequest)))
            .andExpect(status().isCreated())
```

Comment: `status().isCreated()` produce same error `The method andExpect(ResultMatcher) is undefined` for the type MockHttpServletRequestBuilder

Comment: My code in previous open question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867824/how-to-check-json-response-in-spring-mvc-test