# How to test Json correctly using mockmvc (Java)? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: json, spring, rest, testing, mockmvc

I'm just starting to learn Spring.

The controller accepts and returns Json. I can't test it.

**Controller**

```
     @RestController
        @RequestMapping("/service")
        @Slf4j
        public class OrderController {
            private final OrderService orderService;
            private final ConvertService convertService;
        
            @Autowired
            public OrderController(OrderService orderService, ConvertService convertService) {
                this.orderService = orderService;
                this.convertService = convertService;
            }
        
            @GetMapping
            public String getOrderList(@RequestBody String json) {
                String customer = convertService.toOrder(json).getCustomer();
                List<Order> orderList = orderService.findOrderListByCustomer(customer);
                return convertService.toJson(orderList);
            }
        
            @PostMapping
        @ResponseBody
        @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public String saveOrder(@RequestBody OrderDTO orderDTO) throws JsonProcessingException {

        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(orderDTO)
            }
        
        }
```

**ControllerTest**

```
  @SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class OrderControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    private String json;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setData() {
        json = new Gson().toJson(new OrderDTO ("user1",23));
    }

    @Test
    void getJsonTest() throws Exception {

        mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .get("/sb/service")
                .header("Accept","application/json")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(json))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

     @Test
void postJsonTest() throws Exception {


    mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
            .post("/sb/service")
            .header("Accept","application/json")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(json))

            .andExpect(status().isOk());

}

}
```

When testing, I always get 404. But if I send a request from Postman, the response is 200.
I studied this answer, but it didn't help
[How to check JSON response in Spring MVC test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867824/how-to-check-json-response-in-spring-mvc-test)

TestResults

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /sb/service
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json;charset=UTF-8", Accept:"application/json", Content-Length:"30"]
             Body = {"customer":"user1","cost":23}
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 404
    Error message = null
          Headers = [Vary:"Origin", "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers"]
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []


java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<404>
Expected :200
Actual   :404
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you share your code where you've set up your mockMvc? Does the path really match? Are there some general prefixes to your Controller Paths like `api/v1` for example or does it really map down to `/sb/service` ?

Comment: You aren't including the accept header. Also why manually convert to/from String? Spring will do all that for you, not sure why you need the manual conversion (looks like you are working around than rather with the framework). If adding the header doesn't help please add the full test case and not only the test method.

Comment: Added code. The common prefix is only for the application /sb. If you send a request from Postman, the controller works correctly

Comment: M. Deinum, I corrected the code, but the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

It might also be because of your Controller method accepting a Spring instead of an Object, you can let Spring take care of it

My controller looks like this

```
@PostMapping
@ResponseBody
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public String processOrder(@RequestBody OrderDTO orderDTO)
```

As long as your object (orderDTO in my case) has all the fields (with same name) as in your json, and all the getters, setters and allArgsConstructor it should work

Comment: added using Gson to automatically convert object to JSON. Result is the same

Comment: please see my updated answer and let me know if it helps

Comment: added annotations to @Postmapping for the test. The test does not pass, the result is attached

Comment: It wasn’t about the annotations it was about using an object and not a String as a parameter. Also can you update the code so I can see how it looks now.

Comment: Edited controller, method saveOrder. Removed all of the business logic. An object is received and returned. It's supposed to work?
From Postman post-query works.
Иге the test does not pass

Comment: you are posting/getting to `sb/service` but  your controller methods are getting/posting at `/service`

Comment: server.servlet.context-path=/sb

Comment: Once again remind. From Postman, all get and post requests work correctly. It turns out that the problem is with the implementation of tests.

Comment: I`m understand. The error is not in the code, the error is in the my DNA

Comment: I made Autowired OrderService, saved the object to the database and the test worked fine. I used to add OrderService with MockBean annotation and it didn't save anything to the database.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I wasted your time